# ConTeXt: Removing whitespace in itemize in footnote

Tags: lists, footnotes, context, itemize

I’d like to include a list inside a footnote, but without the default whitespace.

It doesn’t respect document-wide settings. I tried overriding it with `[nowhite]` directly inside the footnote, but that doesn’t remove the first blank line. I also tried to create a simple setups duplicating the document-wide setup and applying it with `\setupnote[footnote][setups=footer:itemize]`, but that did not have any effect.

```tex
\setuppapersize [S6]
\setupitemize [nowhite]

\starttext
Footnote
\startfootnote
% There is whitespace here
\startitemize
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
\stopitemize
\stopfootnote

% But not here
\startitemize
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

[image: rendered example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\setuppapersize[S6]
\starttext
Footnote
\startfootnote
\blank[-line]
\startitemize[before=]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\stopitemize
\stopfootnote
\startitemize
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, do you have any way to set it in the preamble? I guess it’s fine mixing formatting into text in this one case, but I’d rather avoid it generally.

Comment: @JurajFiala Is it fine to define a new list environment for footnotes in order to avoid issues with the default `\startitemize ... \stopitemize`?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question. My point is that I want to separate form from content; thus I want to avoid style overrides in the content itself.

Comment: @JurajFiala You're able to define `\startmyitemize ... \stopmyitemize` or whatever name you want it, so that it works in footnotes and you still have the default list environment. Otherwise, it's very complicated to hack the default environment so that it does what you need in each case.